# Create associative list with variables as values in common lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I am looking for creating an associative list (common lisp) with variables as values.

Let me explain better with (dummy) code:

```
(defun mylist-create (val1 val2)
  (setq alist '((key1    . val1)
                (key2     . val2)))
  ;; do other things here
  ;; and return the list 
  alist)

(format t "~a~%" (mylist-create "toto" "tata"))
```

The problem here is that "val1" and "val2" are not considered as variables since the list is not created with their values but with their names.

How can I extract their value within the list creation ?
Is "setf and assoc" the only solution to add a key/value pair?

Comment: `Alist` is a global variable (which may or may not also be globally special). Your Lisp implementation should give you a warning about that. Use `let` to make local bindings instead.

Comment: Of course I used "let", I was giving a simple & dummy example. Thank for this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quasiquoting is the way to selectively allow dereferenced values into your quoted form.

```
(let ((x 10) (y 20))
   `((x . ,x)
     (y . ,y)))

=> ((X . 10) (Y . 20))
```

So you use a backtick to start a quasiquote and you use comma before the form that you want to have evaluated before it enters to the quoted form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: This works, but depends on knowing the structure of the association list.  It might be nicer to just use pairlis:  (pairlis '(x y) (list x y)) => ((y . 20) (x . 10))

Answer (score 3):

It's because you jsut quoted all the list.

You need to use smething like acons to build such lists:

```
CL-USER> (defvar *a* "A variable") 
*A*
CL-USER> '((a . *a*))
((A . *A*))
CL-USER> (acons a *a* '())
((1 . "A variable"))
CL-USER>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine, but it's also nice to know that in addition to **acons** (for adding a new entry to an association list), the standard also provides [**pairlis**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pairli.htm), which can add multiple entries to an association list, or create a new association list.  E.g.,

```
(pairlis '(key1 key2) (list 42 78))
;=> ((key2 . 78) (key1 . 42))

(pairlis '(key1 key2) (list 42 78) '((a . 1) (b . 2))
;=> ((key2 . 78) (key1 . 42) (a . 1) (b . 2))
```